how to pass valarray or vector as argument in C++20
I want a function that can take either a valarray or vector as an argument. The (trivial sample) code below works fine in C++17 (compiles, runs, and gives the right answer), but fails to compile in C++20 with the error message

'GetSum': no matching overloaded function found

It works if I call the pointer version directly, but it's obviously neater if I can just pass the container.
template<class T>
T GetSum(std::valarray<T>& vIn)
{
    return GetSum(&vIn[0], vIn.size());
}

template<class T>
T GetSum(std::vector<T>& vIn)
{
    return GetSum(&vIn[0], vIn.size());  // could use .data() here
}

// pointer version
template<class T>
T GetSum(T* vIn, size_t n)
{
    T sum{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += vIn[i];
    return sum;
}


void OnTest()
{
    std::vector<double> vec(10, 1);
    std::valarray<int> val(3, 10);

    double x = GetSum(vec);
    int i = GetSum(val);
...

Sorry for my ignorance, but can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
(FYI I asked a question on this topic a while back, which was how I got the C++17 code working OK, but now I'm trying to move to C++20 and find that my code no longer works).

please include a [mcve] and the complete error message in the question

Just move the pointer version before the other two versions. See working demo Basically you're calling the pointer version before declaring it.


can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The problem is that you're trying to call the pointer version of GetSum before declaring it. In other words, when you wrote GetSum(&vIn[0], vIn.size()) the compiler can't find the suitable version because name lookup only considers declaration at or before that point.
To solve this, you can move its declaration before using/calling it as shown below:
//first declare/define this
template<class T>
T GetSum(T* vIn, size_t n)
{
    T sum{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += vIn[i];
    return sum;
}

//now you can use the above
template<class T>
T GetSum(std::vector<T>& vIn)
{
    //now this'll work because we've already declared the pointer version above
    return GetSum(&vIn[0], vIn.size());  
}

template<class T>
T GetSum(std::valarray<T>& vIn)
{
    return GetSum(&vIn[0], vIn.size());
}

Working demo

Thanks for the ultra-fast solution. But why on earth did it work OK in C++17 (and 14) before that? Is this a new restriction in C++20? Or did I just get lucky with a compiler glitch in the previous version??

@BillHeitler It doesn't work in c++17 also. See demo. You're welcome.

Well, honestly for the past several years the code has compiled and run in Visual Studio, including VS2022, with first c++14 and then c++17 settings. It was only when I changed to c++20 that the issue became apparent. I don't know if the earlier MS versions had some work-around, or if I just got lucky that an undetected undefined behaviour came up with the right answer. But I'm thankful for your solution (which certainly makes sense), and I will look out for it in future.

@BillHeitler I think you might not be compiling your c++17 code with /permissive- flag. This flag is automatically used in c++20. While in c++17 and c++14 you must use it explicitly writing /permissive-. Note the - at the end of the flag. Try compiling your program with this flag and c++17 or c++14 and you'll notice that msvc will reject it. See demo you'll notice that it is in fact the case. So as a rule of thumb, always compile msvc program with /permissive- flag.

You are quite right. The conformance flag was set to Default in both versions, but I had not noticed that the default had changed in C++20! That explains quite a lot of the code changes I had to make in migrating to C++20. Thank you for your time and trouble in responding to this question.
